# CSRFToken with Django backend and React frontend

Tags: reactjs, django, csrf-token

I'm trying to set up CSRF cookies between my django backend and react front end.

Currently on my backend I have these two view:

```
@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')
class GetCSRFToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'success': 'CSRF cookie set'})

@method_decorator(csrf_protect, name='dispatch')
class LoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request=request, username=username, password=password)

        try:
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'User is authenticated'})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Either password or username is invalid, try again'}, status=400)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Something went wrong when authenticating'})
```

When I test them using Postman they work. I just call the CSRF cookie and copy that cookie and paste it into the X-CSRFToken header of the login on Postman. So both of them work, but then when I test it using the front end it doesnt. From my research this is what I've done. The top one is a CSRFToken.js and the bottom is a piece of my Login.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

```
const CSRFToken = () => {
    const [csrftoken, setcsrftoken] = useState('');

    const getCookie = (name) => {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                let cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/csrf_cookie');
            } catch (err) {

            }
        };

        fetchData();
        setcsrftoken(getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }, []);

    return (
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value={csrftoken} />
    );
};

export default CSRFToken;
```

---

```
const getCookie = (name) => {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          let cookie = cookies[i].trim();
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}

try {
      var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');


      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',
        {
          username: username,
          password: password,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
          },
        }
      );

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <CSRFToken />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setUsername(e.target.value);
            handleInputChange();
```

---

I know that the cookie is coming back in the response header of the api endpoint as
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=

However, I keep getting the error
[02/Jul/2023 20:38:46] "GET /api/csrf_cookie HTTP/1.1" 200 29
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/login
[02/Jul/2023 20:59:31] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 403 2870